# jquery pass input value to invisible inputfield

Tags: jquery, input

Let's say I have #input1 and #input2. When I click to #input1 I'm receiving value in #input1 but the question is how can I recieve this value in #input1 by clicking on #input2?

```
$(function() {
        $('#input1').jEntropy({
            'rSize'   : '5',
            'pool'    : '12345',
            'message' : 'hello.',
            'disable' : true
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function() {
 $('#input1').jEntropy({
        'rSize'   : '5',
        'pool'    : '12345',
        'message' : 'hello.',
        'disable' : true
    });
 $('#input2').click(function(e){
   $('#input1').focus();
 });
});
```

Comment: This Should kick off the jEntropy code for input1, and store it in input1.  is that what you wanted?